# How to resize webpage content width on mobile to always fit screen at any zoom level?

Tags: javascript, html, mobile-website

I've seen this behavior on some webpages but I can't seem to find any information on how to recreate it. I would like my mobile webpage to be able to resize its content based on the zoom level of the user's device (so that it always occupies 100% of the width).

Imagine a simple text paragraph; how can I make sure it always occupies 100% of the width of the phone as the user zooms in and out?

Comment: Please don't do this - mssing with the native UI just makes life difficult for users. They become familiar with how *their* device works, please let them zoom, pan and change to landscape or portrait as they see fit. By all means make sure your layout is suitable for moblie (which usually means don't have very wide columns or tiny text), but please leave the native UI alone. :-)

Comment: Right but on desktop i want to have very wide columns. I modifying the width on mobile so that it becomes the size of their screen. Problem is the text might be to small for some. Are you suggesting that for those that think its too small, to let them zoom in and pan around?

Answer (score 1):

This is built-in to the mobile web browser. You do not need to do anything special. Test your site in the mobile web-browser and you will see it already has this functionality.

Comment: I would've thought the behavior would be similar to resizing your browser window since all my tags have width:100%.I've been testing on a Samsung Galaxy S phone and using the zoom buttons on the bottom have the right behavior and so does pinching out afterwards. But pinching to zoom in doesn't cause any resizing.

Comment: Does pinching in to zoom work as you expect it to on any other sites on that Galaxy S's browser?

Comment: I've seen it once or twice (can't remember the websites unfortunately). I've done a few tests on both an iphone and my galaxy and neither seem to have the default behaviour of resizing a webpage on pinch to zoom. Any blog for example, when you pinch to zoom, you end up seeing a part of the text width. My goal is to have the text wrap into the smaller viewable area.